# Error setting boost libraries path in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I have encountered a problem after setting the path of boost libraries in Eclipse. I get an error like:

```
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my **log**:

```
15:32:06 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Demo ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0" "-includeC:\\boost_1_66_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Demo.o" "..\\src\\Demo.cpp" 
cc1plus: fatal error: C:\boost_1_66_0: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

15:32:06 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 147ms)
```

Comment: It seems that there is no folder C:\boost_1_66_0. What is the path to boost? You configured two different paths: C:\boost\boost_1_66_0 and C:\boost_1_66_0

Comment: i just gave single path of boost library, but it shows like that

Comment: You configured the wrong include path.

Comment: I have given the path like                                                                                                               Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0" "-includeC:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Demo.o" "..\\src\\Demo.cpp" 
cc1plus: fatal error: C:\boost\boost_1_66_0: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your paths aren’t aligned for the -l flag and the -include flag. It  should be “-includeC:\boost\boost_1_66_0”, or the correct path to the boost root directory.

See this [boost doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) for more info.

Comment: i have given the path for both '-I' and '-include', "C:\boost\boost_1_66_0"

Comment: The code you posted shows the include path and l path are different.

Comment: Later i have changed, again it shows like          Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0" "-includeC:\\boost\\boost_1_66_0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Demo.o" "..\\src\\Demo.cpp" 
cc1plus: fatal error: C:\boost\boost_1_66_0: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.